# Code meant for form validation success running even when validation fails

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am posting form data to Mongo. When there are no errors the form should reset and a success message shows. but what is happening now is that when there are validation errors the form resets and the success message shows.

```
onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
  try {
     const response = await fetch(//code here);
     const responseData = await response.json();

     if (!response.okay) {
          setErrors(responseData);
     }

     setSuccess(true);
     resetForm();

  } catch(err) {
     console.log(err);
  {
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a simple oversight. You are running the `setSuccess` even if the form fails. Just put the 2 functions in an `else`.

Also, `response.okay` doesn't exist in the fetch API and you should use `response.ok` to get the expected results.

```
onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
  try {
     const response = await fetch(//code here);
     const responseData = await response.json();

     if (!response.ok) {
          setErrors(responseData);
     } else {
         setSuccess(true);
         resetForm();
     }
  } catch(err) {
     console.log(err);
  }
}}
```

Comment: That's the thing I forgot to mention. I already tried that but still doesn't work. When the form validation succeeds the success message doesn't show and the form doesn't reset.

Comment: The ```response.okay``` doesn't exist in the fetch api. The correct version would be ```response.ok```. It should work correctly then, assuming you are providing correct response codes :)

Comment: AH! Not sure why I had .okay instead of .ok. No wonder, haha. Thanks for that!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Should be an else for the success condition.

```
    if (!response.okay) {
        setErrors(responseData);
    }
    else{
        setSuccess(true);
        resetForm();
    }
```

Comment: That's the thing I forgot to mention. I already tried that but still doesn't work. When the form validation succeeds the success message doesn't show and the form doesn't reset.